# saving turtle graphics without a monitor output

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have some python code which draws some shapes which I save as an EPS document. This works fine on my mac, however I want this to run on a server which doesnt have a monitor or any visual output device connected to it.

The following code works fine on my laptop, but when running on my server it creates the file, however the file is empty. Is this because there isn't a "output" involved. Or have I fundamentally misunderstood whats going on?

```
import turtle

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.circle(20)

x = myTurtle.getscreen()
x.getcanvas().postscript(file = "output.eps")
```

Comment: What OS is your headless machine? Do other Python programs work on it? Can you please try out the following code and tell us the result (i.e. if `output.txt` was created and if it contained the string):
`open("output.txt", "w").write("Hello! File writing is fine!")`

Comment: Hi, The OS on the machine I'm using is scientific linux. The above line of code works fine.

Comment: let's try surrounding that and logging exceptions: http://pastebin.com/51rKpddr